# Which version of VC++ is wcstof added

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

We are using the below code in our product which is built using VS++  2017 compiler.

```
 wchar_t currentVersion[30];
 wchar_t * pEnd;  
 d1 = wcstof(currentVersion, &pEnd`);
```

The code is getting compiled and running successfully. Now I have to port this code to an older version of our product which is built in VS 2008. When I run this code against VS 2008 compiler I get the error message that wcstof identifier not found. I have included the headers like wchar.h and TChar.h. So it looks that wcstof is not supported with 2008 VS. Am i right ? What is the alternative API I can use here ?

Comment: 2017 to 2008 ...awww... :| Good Luck !

Comment: It is not a full migration. I just need to import this single fix to older version of C++. Want to know whats the equivalent of wcstof we can use for VS 2008 compiler

Comment: `stof()` was introduced in C++11

Comment: Maybe `swscanf()` or something like that would work.

Answer (score 0):

[`wcstof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstof) was added to the C++ standard only with C++11. So it is very *unlikely* that compiler versions before 2011 provided support for this.

Based on [this](http://video.ch9.ms/sessions/teched/na/2014/DEV-B223.pptx) link we can say that VS 2013 supports this function.